# How do I separate conditions for when a user is 18 and able to vote and 21 to be able to gamble?

Tags: c++

Here is what I have so far for my first mini-solo project into the world of coding, but I cannot figure out how to separate my conditions below. Any help?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  // Constants
  const double SIXTEEN = 16;
  const double EIGHTEEN = 18;
  const double TWENTYONE = 21;

  // Variables for user input
  int numSixteen;    // To hold number for sixteen yr olds
  int numEighteen;   // To hold number for Eighteen yr olds
  int numTwentyone;  // To hold number for Twenty one yr olds

  // Variable for calculations
  double total;  // To hold the total

  // Display the objective of the program.
  cout << "Enter age below\n\n";

  // Get the age enter code here
  cout << "Enter your age: ";
  cin >> total;

  // Determine the results.
  if (total >= SIXTEEN)
    cout << "\nYou are allowed to drive.\n"
         << EIGHTEEN - total << " years until you can vote.\n"
         << TWENTYONE - total << " years until you can gamble.\n";
  else if (total < SIXTEEN)
    cout << SIXTEEN - total << " years until you can drive.\n"
         << EIGHTEEN - total << " years until you can vote.\n"
         << TWENTYONE - total << " years until you can gamble.\n";

  if (total >= EIGHTEEN) cout << "You are allowed to vote.";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the output need to be in this order? Does driving have to come before voting and etc.?

Comment: Worth pointing out that pre-edit, your code formatting was horrendous. Indenting for no reason, poor spacing, etc. Proper formatting makes code easier to understand. If you don't want to do it yourself, there are tools like clang-format that will do it for you.

Comment: Using `SIXTEEN` instead of 16 in this case is silly - 16 isn't a magic number whose value might change in the future. 16 will always be 16. If you made it a meaningful constant, like `DRIVING_AGE`, it would be worth it, as the driving age might change in the future (it could be moved to 15 or 17, for instance). The same with `EIGHTEEN` and `TWENTYONE` - as is, they're useless, but if they were `VOTING_AGE` and `GAMBLING_AGE` they would make sense - they would actually make the code more readable, too.

Comment: Also worth noting: there's no reason to use `double` in any of your numerics. You're not looking for partial years (16.5, for example). There's no need to use floating point values for 16, 18 and 21. Declaring them as `int` would be more proper.

Comment: What have you written so far? I don't see anything in your question.

Comment: I've rolled back your question so that it makes sense and is self-contained. Otherwise, it's not clear what you're having problems with and the answer below makes no sense in context

Answer (score 2):

```
  if (total >= 16)
    cout << "You are allowed to drive.\n";
  else
    cout << 16-total << " years until you can drive.\n";

  if (total >= 18)
    cout << "You are allowed to vote.\n";
  else
    cout << 18-total << " years until you can vote.\n";

  if (total >= 21)
    cout << "You are allowed to gamble.\n";
  else
    cout << 21-total << " years until you can gamble.\n";
```